# Java code to create AFP file

Tags: afp

I wanted to create AFP file using Java.The file contains images, dynamic data like username , coloured texts and pictures. Just wanted to create electricity light bill.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, There are two ways to create AFP files using java.

1. Using XSLT and FOP, In this
   you have to use xslt style sheeting over xml data and then apply FOP over it.FOP provide multiple options to create multiple docs. like pdf,afp etc
   refer this-> [https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/output.html][1]
2. Using Japer report.

Answer (score 0):

Using jasper you need to create the jasper report then populate it using JavaBean or data source.Then use that compiled jasper file to the Afp printer driver of IBM which converts the file to the AFP file.